# AttributeError when using cloudscraper object in asynchronous function

Tags: python, python-asyncio, attributeerror

```
import cloudscraper
import requests
import asyncio
async def scrape_prices():
    scraper_object = cloudscraper.create_scraper()
    async with scraper_object as session:
        for item_number in prices_to_be_scraped:
            hyperlink = "https://opensea.io/assets/" +
            str(get_contract_address(get_project_name())) + "/" + str(
            item_number)
            async with str(scraper_object.get(hyperlink).text) as response:
                print(await response)
```

ERROR IM GETTING IN TERMINAL:

> async with scraper_object as session:
> AttributeError: __aenter __

Comment: You can only use `async with` with asyncio-aware content managers. It looks like cloudscraper is not asyncio-aware; just use `with`.

Comment: You’ll run into another error when you try to use the return value of `str` as a context manager.

Comment: I changed my code and now im getting a new error: "TypeError: object Response can't be used in 'await' expression". Is there any way to asynchronously make http requests with clouscraper?

Comment: I don’t know what cloudscraper is. If it isn’t asyncio-aware your best bet will be to use threads. Take a look at concurrent.futures.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue, and I found this library https://pypi.org/project/aiocfscrape/ which should be doing the same as cloudscraper does but asynchronous.

The use example that they show in the documents is this one:

```
    import asyncio
    from aiocfscrape import CloudflareScraper
    
    async def test_open_page(url):
        async with CloudflareScraper() as session:
            async with session.get(url) as resp:
                return await resp.text()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        asyncio.run(test_open_page('<your url>'))
```

I hope you find this library useful.